# Autofac Injection by Caller Type

Tags: autofac

Is it possible to inject type to using autofac by the caller type?

I have 2 objects that holds the same member type. 
What I want is when `Container1` is called Autofac resolve `IRegisteredType` as `RegisteredType` with one value as the `name` parameter on the `ctor` and different value for  `Container2` resolve.

```
class Container1
{
    private IRegisteredType _registeredType;

    public Container1(IRegisteredType registeredType)
    {
        _registeredType = registeredType;
    }

}

class Container2
{
    private IRegisteredType _registeredType;

    public Container2(IRegisteredType registeredType)
    {
        _registeredType = registeredType;
    }

}

public interface IRegisteredType{}

public class RegisteredType:IRegisteredType
{ 
    public RegisteredType(string name(){...} 
}
```